# Are there any pros and cons for code maintenance when using the default settings of the Cadence Versioning API?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I've heard that using the Cadence versioning API with the default settings can have both positive and negative consequences for code maintenance depending on how you want to use it. Can anyone briefly summarise the pros and cons of this?

Thanks!